# I want to find the number of steps it takes to find the GCD by Euclidean Algorithm

Tags: number-theory

Let's say I have two numbers a and b. I want to find the number of steps it takes to find the GCD by Euclidean Algorithm by a closed formula which includes parameter a and b.
If I go by this implementation , in how many steps will I reach gcd:

```
 public static int gcd(int a, int b) 
    { 
        if (a == 0) 
            return b; 

        return gcd(b%a, a); 
    }
```

Comment: "I want to find the number of steps". It might not occur to you that simple statement is in fact ambiguous. Very ambiguous. Do you want to have a closed formula given parameter $a$ and $b$? Do you want to get lower or upper bound of that number? Or do you want to find an algorithm that will output that number? What counts as one step?

Comment: I want to find a closed formula given parameter  a and b

Comment: Please edit the question to clarify your intention. By the way, there is no closed formula.

Comment: By "closed formula" do you mean "closed formula for worst-case runtime"? If that's the case, the worst-case runtime for the Euclidean algorithm is $O(n^2)$ when the two inputs are of $n$ bits in length. The detailed proof requires some delicate analysis.

Comment: @BearAqua  "the worst-case runtime for the Euclidean algorithm is $(n^2)$ when the two inputs are of $n$ bits in length". That is certainly correct although far from the optimal, $O(n)$. In fact, it is not greater than $m$ where $F_{m+2}$ is the least Fibonacci number that is not less than either of $a$ and $b$, assuming both $a$ and $b$ are positive. See [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#Worst-case)

Comment: @Apass.Jack I think I should clarify that I meant **each** input are of $n$ bits in length; in that case, I think the worst-case runtime is quadratic. At any rate the precise runtime is never linear in bits, otherwise there won't be so many literature on subquadratic-time gcd / Jacobi algorithms.

Comment: @Apass.Jack Are you assuming that division works in constant time?

Comment: Now I see that we were talking about different things. You were talking about bit by bit. I was talking about number of steps in the algebraic model. For beginners, we rarely dive into the bit by bit model although it is a very important and practical model, that was why I did not realized your point of view.

Comment: @Apass.Jack Thanks, now it makes sense :-)

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of examples of the algorithm implementation online.
[Here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/euclidean-algorithms-basic-and-extended/) is one such example which also has it in Java.

From there modifying your code to count the steps should be trivial.

Comment: You are correct but I was trying to find a formula for the same which depends on either a or b . I could modify the gcd implementation but that would work only for small numbers . if a or b are large , running time of the algorithm would be very high.

Comment: No, you were not trying to find a formula. You were trying to avoid finding a formula by asking people. What have you actually tried? Have you tried the algorithm? Maybe by hand?

Answer (score 0):

In case someone with real interest runs into this problem:

Start with a and b, then perform two steps. Observe how both a and b become smaller. Assume the result after two steps is a'', b'', then find a constant c < 1 so that you can guarantee a'' < c*a, and b'' < c*b.

With that you can easily find an upper bound to the number of steps, and for some pairs of numbers that upper bound will be achieved. (Try gcd (55, 34) and what do you observe? )

Comment: (Hint: Those are Fibonacci numbers.)